# Bootstrap submitting form to php and reading the returned xml

Tags: php, xml, twitter-bootstrap

I use the following markup:

```
<form action="http://mysite.com/contactmail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Contact us</legend>

<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
         <label class="control-label" title="inputName" for="inputName">Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" required class="span3" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>

    <label class="control-label" title="inputEmail" for="inputEmail">E-mail</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="email" required class="span3" id="inputEmail" placeholder="E-mail">
    </div>

    <label class="control-label" title="inputMessage" for="inputMessage">Message</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <textarea rows="3" required class="span5" id="inputMessage" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
    </div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

And the following contactmail.php:

```
<?php

$Name = htmlspecialchars($_GET['inputName']); 
$Email = htmlspecialchars($_GET['inputEmail']); 
$Message=htmlspecialchars($_GET['inputMessage']);
$to="mail@mysite.com";
$subject="Contact form";

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
    $headers  .= "From: $Name <$Email>\r\n"; 
    // $headers .= "Reply-To: $to\r\n";

  $SendState = mail($to, $subject, $Message, $headers);

    if ($SendState) {

$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<mailer>
  <response>'Success'</response>
  <comment>'Message send'</comment>
 </mailer>
XML;

}
    else {
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<mailer>
 <response>'Failed'</response>
  <comment>'An unknown error occurred'</comment>
</mailer>
XML;
};
echo $xmlstr;
?>
```

Update, I adjusted the php file as follows, but I don't get the result on the original page:

```
 if ($SendState) {

print "<html><div class=\"alert alert-success\">Message sent successfully</div></html>";

}
    else {
print "<html><div class=\"alert alert-error\">Failed: An Error occured</div></html>";
};

?>
```

When I click the submit button, an email is send, but without any data. I see the XML, but I want the user to stay on the page and give an error message on that page when it failed to send and a green success message when send.

So the question is, what am I doing wrong, how do I pass the data?
How to handle the XML that is returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, most of the developers print the error/success on the HTML page itself(output of `contactmail.php`). I have two different solutions for you.

1. Remove the XML and just print the HTML as below (Bootstrap compatible):

For success:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">Message sent successfully</div>
```

For error:

```
<div class="alert alert-error">Failed: An Error occured</div>
```

2. If you need an XML output, you can associate with an XSL(stylesheet) to display the message appropriately. You can get it how to done here http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: Still no data and I don't get an error message on the contact page, but a new page with the message 'Message sent successfully' opens.

Comment: Can I know what data you are expecting, are you speaking about the mail or the output in screen? For your above code, the HTML output will only be Message sent successfully.

Comment: I figured it out. I meant the $_POST was empty, but I misplaced the <form>